# yocto - User-Agent: falling back to 'libdnf': could not detect OS or basearch

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, openembedded

I am using **Yocto (Hardknott)** to build an image and to create the package-feed(rpm packages). One of the image dependencies is `u-boot-karo` ([it's a custom u-boot for karo modules](https://github.com/karo-electronics/meta-karo/tree/hardknott/recipes-bsp/u-boot)) and it seems this recipe has some issue with the `libdnf`. Could anyone help me with this, below you will find more details about the error from the *do_rootfs.log*

```
NOTE: ###### Generate rootfs #######
NOTE: Executing '/amr-bsp/build/tmp/work/amr1-poky-linux-gnueabi/amr-image-dev/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/createrepo_c --update -q /amr-bsp/build/tmp/work/amr1-poky-linux-gnueabi/amr-image-dev/1.0-r0/oe-rootfs-repo' ...
NOTE: Running /amr-bsp/build/tmp/work/amr1-poky-linux-gnueabi/amr-image-dev/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/dnf -v --rpmverbosity=info -y -c /amr-bsp/build/tmp/work/amr1-poky-linux-gnueabi/amr-image-dev/1.0-r0/rootfs/etc/dnf/dnf.conf --setopt=reposdir=/amr-bsp/build/tmp/work/amr1-poky-linux-gnueabi/amr-image-dev/1.0-r0/rootfs/etc/yum.repos.d --installroot=/amr-bsp/build/tmp/work/amr1-poky-linux-gnueabi/amr-image-dev/1.0-r0/rootfs --setopt=logdir=/amr-bsp/build/tmp/work/amr1-poky-linux-gnueabi/amr-image-dev/1.0-r0/temp --repofrompath=oe-repo,/amr-bsp/build/tmp/work/amr1-poky-linux-gnueabi/amr-image-dev/1.0-r0/oe-rootfs-repo makecache --refresh
DEBUG: DNF version: 4.6.0
cachedir: /amr-bsp/build/tmp/work/amr1-poky-linux-gnueabi/amr-image-dev/1.0-r0/rootfs/var/cache/dnf
Added oe-repo repo from /amr-bsp/build/tmp/work/amr1-poky-linux-gnueabi/amr-image-dev/1.0-r0/oe-rootfs-repo
Making cache files for all metadata files.
oe-repo: has expired and will be refreshed.
repo: downloading from remote: oe-repo
oe-repo                                         343 MB/s | 1.2 MB     00:00    
oe-repo: using metadata from Thu 14 Apr 2022 12:20:13 PM UTC.
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:01 ago on Thu 14 Apr 2022 12:20:13 PM UTC.
User-Agent: falling back to 'libdnf': could not detect OS or basearch
Metadata cache created.

NOTE: Running /amr-bsp/build/tmp/work/amr1-poky-linux-gnueabi/amr-image-dev/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/dnf -v --rpmverbosity=info -y -c /amr-bsp/build/tmp/work/amr1-poky-linux-gnueabi/amr-image-dev/1.0-r0/rootfs/etc/dnf/dnf.conf --setopt=reposdir=/amr-bsp/build/tmp/work/amr1-poky-linux-gnueabi/amr-image-dev/1.0-r0/rootfs/etc/yum.repos.d --installroot=/amr-bsp/build/tmp/work/amr1-poky-linux-gnueabi/amr-image-dev/1.0-r0/rootfs --setopt=logdir=/amr-bsp/build/tmp/work/amr1-poky-linux-gnueabi/amr-image-dev/1.0-r0/temp --repofrompath=oe-repo,/amr-bsp/build/tmp/work/amr1-poky-linux-gnueabi/amr-image-dev/1.0-r0/oe-rootfs-repo --nogpgcheck install alsa-utils-alsamixer alsa-utils-amixer alsa-utils-aplay amr-ipconfig avahi-daemon avahi-utils avahiservice bash canutils coreutils dhcpcd dosfstools e2fsprogs e2fsprogs-resize2fs file gdbserver i2c-tools initscript kernel-modules kmod ldd less libgpiod libgpiod-tools libstdc++ lsof mmc-utils ncurses nfs-utils nginx ntp ntpdate packagegroup-base-extended packagegroup-core-boot packagegroup-core-ssh-openssh parted psplash rauc rsync run-postinsts ssh-keys strace sudo systemd tcp-wrappers tzdata u-boot-karo ufw util-linux util-linux-fsck util-linux-mkfs util-linux-mount util-linux-setterm locale-base-de-de
ERROR: Could not invoke dnf. Command '/amr-bsp/build/tmp/work/amr1-poky-linux-gnueabi/amr-image-dev/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/dnf -v --rpmverbosity=info -y -c /amr-bsp/build/tmp/work/amr1-poky-linux-gnueabi/amr-image-dev/1.0-r0/rootfs/etc/dnf/dnf.conf --setopt=reposdir=/amr-bsp/build/tmp/work/amr1-poky-linux-gnueabi/amr-image-dev/1.0-r0/rootfs/etc/yum.repos.d --installroot=/amr-bsp/build/tmp/work/amr1-poky-linux-gnueabi/amr-image-dev/1.0-r0/rootfs --setopt=logdir=/amr-bsp/build/tmp/work/amr1-poky-linux-gnueabi/amr-image-dev/1.0-r0/temp --repofrompath=oe-repo,/amr-bsp/build/tmp/work/amr1-poky-linux-gnueabi/amr-image-dev/1.0-r0/oe-rootfs-repo --nogpgcheck install alsa-utils-alsamixer alsa-utils-amixer alsa-utils-aplay amr-ipconfig avahi-daemon avahi-utils avahiservice bash canutils coreutils dhcpcd dosfstools e2fsprogs e2fsprogs-resize2fs file gdbserver i2c-tools initscript kernel-modules kmod ldd less libgpiod libgpiod-tools libstdc++ lsof mmc-utils ncurses nfs-utils nginx ntp ntpdate packagegroup-base-extended packagegroup-core-boot packagegroup-core-ssh-openssh parted psplash rauc rsync run-postinsts ssh-keys strace sudo systemd tcp-wrappers tzdata u-boot-karo ufw util-linux util-linux-fsck util-linux-mkfs util-linux-mount util-linux-setterm locale-base-de-de' returned 1:
DNF version: 4.6.0
cachedir: /amr-bsp/build/tmp/work/amr1-poky-linux-gnueabi/amr-image-dev/1.0-r0/rootfs/var/cache/dnf
Added oe-repo repo from /amr-bsp/build/tmp/work/amr1-poky-linux-gnueabi/amr-image-dev/1.0-r0/oe-rootfs-repo
User-Agent: falling back to 'libdnf': could not detect OS or basearch
repo: using cache for: oe-repo
oe-repo: using metadata from Thu 14 Apr 2022 12:20:13 PM UTC.
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:01 ago on Thu 14 Apr 2022 12:20:13 PM UTC.
No match for argument: u-boot-karo
Error: Unable to find a match: u-boot-karo
```

Comment: Is this related to programming?

Comment: It's a build system issue

Comment: To build an app? a software?

Comment: To build an image(os) for embedded use.